# Does a rich:tab allow reRender attribute? If yes - would it reRender a component on that tab when that rich:tab is selected?

Tags: java, combobox, richfaces

Does a rich:tab allow reRender attribute? If yes - would it reRender a component on that tab when that rich:tab is selected?
I am trying to re-render a rich:comboBox after clicking on the tab, so that it shows its defaultLabel when reRendered. However, the rich:comboBox shows value from previous selection. Tried binding the component with UIInput variable and resetting its value. without much success. 
My rich:combo is contained in a code somewhat like this.

```
<rich:panel style="width:100%;" header="XXXXXXX" id="outerpanel">
 <fieldset style="width: 98%"><legend>Role DSDSD</legend>
<h:panelGrid id="roleAcoster" columns="1" columnClasses="alignTop" border="0"     cellpadding="30" cellspacing="4">
 <a4j:outputPanel id="a4panel">
<rich:panel header="Available Roles" width="100%" id="xPanel">
 <h:panelGrid columns="3" border="0" columnClasses="alignTop" cellpadding="3">
    <h:outputText value="New York" />
<rich:comboBox value="#{bean.selectedRole}"
 disabled="#{bean.show}"
 valueChangeListener="#{bean.roleSelected}"
 binding="#{bean.roleComboComponent}"
 id="availableCombo" immediate="true" defaultLabel="Select Role"
 enableManualInput="false" width="204px">
 <f:selectItems
    value="#{bean.selectItems['AvailableRoles']}" />
 <f:attribute name="selectItems"
    value="#{bean.selectItems['AvailableRoles']}" />
     <a4j:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true"
    onsubmit="#{rich:component('wait_div')}.show()" 
    oncomplete="#{rich:component('wait_div')}.hide()"
    reRender="role_button_add,roles_panel" />
</rich:comboBox>
<rich:message for="availableCombo" errorClass="errorMessage" />
  </h:panelGrid>
 </rich:panel>
</a4j:outputPanel>
</h:panelGrid> 
</fieldset>
</rich:panel>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rich:tab does have reRender attribute: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/rich/tab.html . So you can re-render any component.